# crawling price gives null , HtmlAgilityPack (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, web-crawler, html-agility-pack

Im trying to get stock data from a website with webcrawler as a hobby project. I got the link to work, i got the Name of the stock but i cant get the price... I dont know how to handle the html code. Here is my code,

```
var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
            htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

            var divs = htmlDocument.DocumentNode.Descendants("div").Where(n => n.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("Flexbox__StyledFlexbox-sc-1ob4g1e-0 eYavUv Row__StyledRow-sc-1iamenj-0 foFHXj Rows__AlignedRow-sc-1udgki9-0 dnLFDN")).ToList();
            var stocks = new List<Stock>();

            foreach (var div in divs)
            { 
                var stock = new Stock()
                {
                    Name = div.Descendants("a").Where(a=>a.GetAttributeValue("class","").Equals("Link__StyledLink-sc-apj04t-0 foCaAq NameCell__StyledLink-sc-qgec4s-0 hZYbiE")).FirstOrDefault().InnerText,
                    changeInPercent = div.Descendants("span").Where((a)=>a.GetAttributeValue("class", "").Equals("Development__StyledDevelopment-sc-hnn1ri-0 kJLDzW")).FirstOrDefault()?.InnerText  
                };
                stocks.Add(stock);
            }

            foreach (var stock in stocks)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(stock.Name + " ");
                

            }
```

I got the Name correct, but i dont really know how the get the ChangeInPercent....  I will past in the html code below,

[image]

The top highlight show where i got the name from, and the second one is the "span" i want. I want the -4.70

Im a litle bit confused when it comes to get the data with my code. I tried everything. My changeInPercent property is a string.

it has to be the code somehow...

Answer (score 0):

There's probably an easier to select a single attribute/node than the way you're doing it right now:

If you know the exact XPath expression to select the node you're looking for, then you can do the following:

```cs
var htmlDocument = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDocument.LoadHtml(html);

var changeInPercent = htmlDocument.DocumentNode
    .SelectSingleNode("//foo/bar")
    .InnerText;
```

Getting the right XPath expression (the `//foo/bar` example above) is the tricky part. But this can be found quite easy using your browser's dev tools. You can navigate to the desired element and just copy it's XPath expression - simple as that! See [here](https://devtoolstips.org/tips/en/copy-element-xpath/) for a sample on how to copy the expression.

Answer (score 0):

F12 is your friend in any browser. Look at the network tab. The data you are interested in is of type "xhr". No need to use HTMLAgilityPack. All you need to do is parse the Json returned by your url.

Write code to download the json string from the URL. The following code works for me :

```
using System.Net;

using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{             
    wc.Headers.Add("accept", "application/json, text/plain, */*");          
    wc.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/104.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");              

    string downloadedJson = wc.DownloadString("https://www.nordnet.se/marknaden/aktiekurser");                 
}
```

Copy the whole result (the value of downloadedJson) on your clipboard.

In Visual Studio create a new class file

Click Edit > Paste special > Paste Json as classes. In your code you will need the name of the first class that you pasted. It is the parent class called Rootobject by default

Install Newtonsoft.Json

using Newtonsoft.Json
Rootobject obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject < Rootobject>(downloadedJson);
Now you can loop through the results array to extract all of the job info you need.

```
    var  results = obj.results;
```